# Understanding Cosine Similarity, PMI, and PCA for a Beginner: Need Advice

Tags: nlp, distribution, semantics

What is the relationship between cosine similarity and Pointwise Mutual Information? And how does Principal Component Analysis (PCA) fit into this? I'm currently working on a Python project that aims to measure word similarity across different centuries, and I'm a bit confused. Should I calculate the cosine similarity on the PMI Matrix? Do you have any suggestions on where I can find tutorials or scripts that serve as a good baseline? Thank you all in advance

Currently, I am performing the following steps for my project:

Creating a co-occurrence matrix with a window size of 5 to capture raw co-occurrences.
Transforming the co-occurrence matrix into a PMI matrix.
Comparing the PMI scores between three specific vectors of interest.
Extracting the vectors of words that co-occur with a particular vector (referred to as VECTOR1), which corresponds to the word I am studying.
Creating a semantic space using VECTOR1 and its associated "co-vectors" as a subregion of the PMI matrix.
Applying PCA to the semantic space and calculating the cosine similarity between VECTOR1 and each of the other co-vectors.